# elasticsearch query to get records between particular date using curl

Tags: elasticsearch

```
curl -X GET 'http://xxx.xxx.x.xx:9200/upslinklog/upslinklog/_search?pretty' -d '{
    "query": {
        "filtered": {
            "query": {
                "match_all": {}
            },
            "filter": {
                "range": {
                    "logTimestamp": {
                        "gte": "2017/05/17", 
            "lte":"2017/05/18"
                "format": "yyyy/mm/dd"
                    }
                }
            }

    }
}
'
```

I want to records after 17/5/2017.Above query code gave all the records rather than some. How to do range query for filtered data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you have to specify your `logTimestamp` as a date in your index configuration.

From **[Elasticsearch documentation "Date datatype"](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/date.html)** :

Example of index configuration :

```
PUT my_index
{
  "mappings": {
    "my_type": {
      "properties": {
        "date": {
          "type": "date" 
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Then you can use simple **[Range Query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-range-query.html)** as following :

```
GET _search
{
    "query": {
        "range" : {
            "born" : {
                "gte": "01/01/2012",
                "lte": "01/01/2013",
                "format": "dd/MM/yyyy"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: logTimestamp is already of type date with format strict_date_optional_time||epoch_millis.

Comment: Why do you use filtered query for a simple range query ? You're making a simple query complexe for nothing.

Comment: difference between range and filtered query ?

Comment: Don't forget to validate the answer to let everybody knows that you have a valid solution and you're not looking for one anymore.